# How to test for the existence of a Class when I can't weak link against it

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a class that is designed to be re-usable but I have included calls to a class which may not always be available when compiled.

To be more specific I am using Flurry analytics and I want to included calls to that - but not every project that this module may be included in will have access to the Flurry library - I simply want it not compile in those bits of code in these situations. The module will be distributed as source code, so it only has to test at compile time.

So far I have tried:

```
if([Flurry class]){
    [Flurry logEvent:@"Blah"];
}
```

This fails "Use of undefined identifier" - Flurry is not defined anywhere, as there is no weak reference to the library

So next tried:

```
Class flurryClass = NSClassFromString(@"Flurry");
if(flurryClass){
  [flurryClass logEvent:@"Blah"];
}
```

This fails as "No known class method for selector logEvent"

So I seem to be stuck, as the first method relies on weak linking a library that may not be available to weak link against! The second method I assume fails as I'm calling a Class method on a Class that is currently has no definition so the compiler complains? Is there any solution to this that anyone can think of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use reflection the whole way through. Change your code to this:

```
Class flurryClass = NSClassFromString(@"Flurry");
if(flurryClass){
  [flurryClass performSelector:@selector(logEvent:) withObject:@"Blah"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks - of course I should have thought of that! Supplementary question, any way of conditionally #import ing the header file only if it exists?

Comment: @SimonBooth You do not need to import the header if you are reflective instantiating classes and invoking selectors.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid having your library automatically log flurry events to someone else's account without their permission. I would recommend preprocessor checks and requiring implementers to explicitly enable Flurry.

```
#if MYLIB_ENABLE_FLURRY

    if([Flurry class]){
        [Flurry logEvent:@"Blah"];
    }

#endif //MYLIB_ENABLE_FLURRY
```

Now if someone wants to add logging from your library you can instruct them that Flurry is required and to compile your library using `-DMYLIB_ENABLE_FLURRY=1` or add it to their Other C Flags if they include the source directly.

Comment: Yes I agree that is a better solution for a more widely distributed bit of code. In this case it's simply for my own projects at the moment - and if I use Flurry for it I want it logging.